# Is いらっしゃいませ only used by staff?

Tags: keigo, greetings

Is いらっしゃいませ only used by staff, or is it used in other circumstances?

When I was at a dinner at a restaurant being held after a programmers' meetup, I thought that I heard it being used by one of the people eating (it could have been the organizer of the dinner for all I know) to welcome a late-comer. Or is it more likely I mis-heard them merely saying [いらっしゃい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/337/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D-and-%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B) or some other form of the verb?

Comment: いらっしゃる is also used instead of 居る in some keigo.

Comment: Is it possible that he just responded with "いらっしゃいました"? I'm not a native, but I think you can use "いらっしゃい" when welcoming someone to your home, or business. It has a connection to "being ready to serve". But this is only what I've heard..

Comment: @Chris いらっしゃい is the imperative form of いらっしゃる, which is the subject honorific form of いる or 来る
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hearty いらっしゃいませ! from the staff or owner brings back happy memories of Japanese restaurant/bar life. いらっしゃい is a perfectly ordinary word of greeting. A person who feels like the 'owner' of the get-together might well shout a いらっしゃいませ especially if alcohol is involved. There is also the possibility of using it ironically or with hostility on a late-comer - again the alcohol issue. In Japan, if you act drunk, you can be safely forthright. Watch a lot of daytime drama to get a handle on the many uses of keigo.

Comment: There was alcohol involved. I was drinking nihonshu while others were mainly drinking beer. +1 for the answer, and for giving an answer rather than a comment.